# Reading special characters in vbs

Tags: vbscript, character-encoding

I am having troubles reading special characters in vbs script.
My reading file goes like this.

```
  ls_folder = "file path"
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set fa = fso.OpenTextFile(ls_folder + f1.Name, 1, False)
  Do While fa.AtEndOfStream <> True
    Line = fa.readline
    'Code
    Next
```

If I open files with N++ I get that encoding is ANSI. I tried using 4th parameter for OpenTextFile but none of 3 values have worked for me. 
Script doesnt read "ł" character. When encoded to ascii it gives value 179.

Is there any other way to declare encoding other than using ADODB.Stream, which allows to declare Charset.

Comment: Why is this tagged sql-server?

Comment: You might want to consider re-tagging this question. None of the current tags are applicable.

Comment: Don't know how to get to it from vbs but StreamReader  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx lets you specify the encoding

Comment: Yes. The tags remained from the question I didn't post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`AscW` function rather than `Asc` one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfw01fx4(v=vs.84).aspx): **AscW** is provided for 32-bit platforms that use Unicode characters. It returns the Unicode (wide) character code, thereby avoiding the conversion from Unicode to `ANSI`.

Note that "`ł`" character (Unicode `U+0142` i.e. decimal `322`) is defined in next `ANSI` code pages:

- `Asc("ł")` returns `179` in `ANSI 1250` *Central Europe* and
- `Asc("ł")` returns `249` in `ANSI 1257` *Baltic*.

For proof, open `charmap.exe` or run my [Alt KeyCode Finder](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602) script:

```
==> mycharmap "ł"
Ch Unicode    Alt?    CP    IME    Alt   Alt0    IME 0405/cs-CZ; CP852; ANSI 1250

 ł  U+0142     322         …66…                  Latin Small Letter L With Stroke
               136  CP852 cs-CZ    136   0179    (ANSI 1250) Central Europe
               136  CP775 et-EE          0249    (ANSI 1257) Baltic

 ł

==>
```

For the sake of completeness, `AscB("ł")` returns `66`…

Answer (score 0):

Add another argument to OpenTextFile to specify 'Unicode'. After the 'False' value which says "don't create the file" add 1 as extra argument.